# table with margin to edge swift2

Tags: swift2, ios9

i would like to build a view like this:
[image]

a table with margin to top,left,right,bottom.

i try this code:

```
self.EinstellungenTable.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 0, right: 8)
```

but the result will be this:
[image]

what is wrong?

Comment: is there nobody who knows the solution? Oo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this result on different ways. These are a couple of options, but this can definitely be done by using different approaches

1. Add the table view to a UIViewController's view and set the margins

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

   ```
   let tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds.insetBy(dx: 8, dy: 8))
   tableView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
   self.view.addSubview(tableView)
   .
   .
   .
   ```

   }

In this way you might want to add the tableView's swipe gesture and move to the UIViewController's, otherwise the 8px-wide area around the table won't be scrollable as it's not part of the table view.

---

2. Work with different backgrounds for each cell and inset the content to fit within the area you want. A very old post (2009) explain how that can be done http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html